# A group with six elements which are given partially by relations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In a textbook I saw the following Group 
$$
  G = \{ 1, x, x^2, y, xy, x^2y \}
$$
and it was said that it is the $S_3$, surely the $S_3$ is a model of this group, but when I set $x^3 = y$ (in $S_3$ the relation would be $x^3 = 1$) I get that
$$
  G = \{ 1, x, x,^2, x^3, x^4, x^5 \}
$$
and this group is cyclic, hence commutative, so could not be the $S_3$. I cannot see were this would be a contradiction to $ G = \{ 1, x, x^2, y, xy, x^2y \}$ so I think this group has at least two models, is this true? So why did my textbook said the group $S_3$ *is* $G = \{ 1, x, x^2, y, xy, x^2y \}$?

Comment: Why did you set $x^3 = y$ and why would that not change what the group is?

Comment: Perhap you meant to put $\,x^3=1=y^2\,$ ...?

Comment: I wanted to derive the group table, and I wanted to derive the outcome of $x^2\cdot x$, in the cases $x^3 = x, x^3 = xy, x^2 y$ I got a contradiction to the fact that all the elements are distinct, but when I put $x^3 = y$ I have no contradiciton, and I got a group which is essentially different from $S_3$.

Comment: @Stefan: you are correct that a list of expressions for the group elements does not typically determine the group. One also needs the relations that simplify products of those group elements. Not only do you need to specify $x^3$, but also $y^2$ and $yx$. Even if $x^3=1$, you need not get $S_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list of expressions for group elements has the nice property that if the expression $u \cdot v$ is in the list, then so are $u$ and $v$. Such a list turns the Cayley graph of the group into a directed acyclic graph with a single source (the identity), or perhaps better a spanning tree with direction. The multiplication in the group is given by the (labeled) edges omitted from the spanning tree.

A wonderful way to create such a directed graph is to decide on a “reduction ordering” on expressions. Many expressions will yield the same group element, so we desire a way to choose the “simplest” expression. If $u\cdot v$ is simplest, then both $u$ and $v$ should be simplest (otherwise why not simplify them).

Such a reduction ordering determines a special set of relations that suffice to actually simplify expressions. These relations are called a “rewriting system” and they are the natural thing: if $u$ is not a simplest form (it equals $v$ where $v$ is simplest), but every proper sub-expression of $u$ is a simplest, then we need the rule $u \mapsto v$.

Doing this for your list of expressions finds the rules $x^3 \mapsto ?$, $y^2 \mapsto ?$ and $yx \mapsto ?$. All other missing edges of the Cayley graph can be found from these by a sort of “translation” or “substitution”.

I believe these are the only possibilities:

$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
x^3 & y^2 & yx & G \\ \hline
1 & 1 & xy & C_6 \\
1 & 1 & x^2y & S_3 \\
y & 1 & xy & C_6 \\
1 & x & xy & C_6 \\
1 & x^2 & xy & C_6 
\end{array}$

As you can see the choices are limited, and not independent. Additionally $C_6$ appears in several disguises.